# Attribute 'ScriptServiceAttribute' cannot be applied to 'MethodName' because the attribute is not valid on this declaration type

Tags: ajax, vb.net, webmethod

Below is the definition of `WebMethod` but I am getting below error

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptService()>
Public Function GetCountryByIP(ipAddress As String) As String
    Return "Hello World"
End Function
```

> Error 132 Attribute 'ScriptServiceAttribute' cannot be applied to 'GetCountryByIP' because the attribute is not valid on this declaration type.

Answer (score 0):

The [error message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30662) is pretty clear.

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) `ScriptServiceAttribute` must be applied to a class and cannot be applied to a method.